# Why the cube is getting to the other cube instead stopping when both colliders hit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't want to use a script with OnTriggerEnter or something like that but to simulate the red cube as a wall and when the blue cube collider hit the red cube collider it should stop. Both cubes have a box collider and on both the Is Trigger is checked true I also tried one of them or both when not checked true. And both colliders size on Z set to 3.

But the blue cube is getting to the red one and not stop when colliding :

[image: Cubes]

The blue cube is getting inside the red one :

[image: Cubes]

I tried to add a rigidbody to the moving cube the blue cube but if using Is Kinematic same behaviour if not using Is Kinematic the blue cube is falling down.

This is the script attached to the blue cube to move it to the target red cube :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public float speed;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

I want that the blue cube will stop when colliding the red cube collider that's why I set them on Z to 3. I don't need physics for now.

Do I need must using OnTriggerEnter in my script for that ?

I thought I tried it too but this seems to be working : Both box colliders on the cubes unchecked set false the is trigger and I added a rigidbody to the moving cube the blue one and unchecked the use gravity and now it seems to be working.

So I need a rigidbody even if I'm not using physics. I wonder why.

[image: This is working. Then why do I need a rigidbody if not using gravity and don't want to use physics ?]

My character is going crazy when trying to make him colliding with the red cube just like I did with the blue cube. But now with the soldier character everything get wrong. The soldier have a rigidbody and a box collider and he is moving forward using animator controller with humanoidwalk animation state :

[image: Not working good with a soldier character I tried also other characters same problem/s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the red cube:**

- Box collider

You don't need a rigidbody on the red cube because you don't want its position or rotation to change.

**On the blue cube:**

- Box collider
- Rigidbody

  - Use Gravity turned off
  - Is Kinematic turned off
- Make the script change the rigidbody's velocity or use `Rigidbody.AddForce` in `FixedUpdate` instead of modifying the transform's position. [This answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/195790/view.html) on the Unity Q&A site by **aldonaletto** can be adopted pretty readily for this:

```
public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public float toVel = 2.5f;
    public float maxVel = 15.0f;
    public float maxForce = 40.0f;
    public float gain = 5f;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 dist = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        dist.y = 0; // ignore height differences

        // calc a target vel proportional to distance (clamped to maxVel)
        Vector3 tgtVel = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(toVel * dist, maxVel);

        // calculate the velocity error
        Vector3 error = tgtVel - rb.velocity;

        // calc a force proportional to the error (clamped to maxForce)
        Vector3 force = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(gain * error, maxForce);
        rb.AddForce(force);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working great for the cubes. But what if I have a character that move by using Animator Controller and the HumanoidWalk animation ? I tried almost any option and combination/s adding to the character a box collider rigidbody played with all options like is kinematic or gravity or is trigger.  How can I make like the cubes but with the character using the humanoidwalk ? I edited my question with a screenshot of the soldier character you can see he it stuck in the ceiling going crazy and the inspector settings.

Comment: @DanielLip In that case I would use raycasts/spherecasts/boxcasts coming out from the character towards the direction of movement to check for collisions, and if there is a collision, have the character move there instead. And use `rigidbody.MovePosition` to move the character.